# Set window transparency in Gnome

Tags: gnome3, gnome-shell, mutter

I'd like to make my IDE window partially transparent. I achieved this in Unity using `compiz` as described in the accepted answer to: [How to make a window transparent in gnome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028/how-to-make-a-window-transparent-in-gnome). However I don't believe `compiz` will work for this with gnome unless I'm mistaken. There WAS a gnome extension for this but it has been abandoned and the github repo is gone. Anyone know of a way to achieve this? I'm on ubuntu 17.10

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's another extension called [Glassy Gnome](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/982/glassy-gnome/) that works with newer versions of `gnome-shell`.

For more details consult [the included `README`](https://github.com/emiapwil/glassy-gnome).

Comment: Thanks I'll try it out when I get home tonight but looks promising!

Comment: This allows me to see the windows below, but not the wallpaper. Can it be fixed? Is there a way to *only* see the wallpaper?

Answer (score 15):

You could change window opacity/transparency by changing property `_NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY` via `xprop` command.

Run:

```
xprop -format _NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY 32c -set _NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY 0x7FFFFFFF
```

and then click on window to set it to 50% opacity.

- `0x7FFFFFFF` - 50% opacity
- `0xFFFFFFFF` - 100% opacity

Set opacity via providing window id (obtained from `xwininfo`):

```
xprop -id 0x3a00006 -format _NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY 32c -set _NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY 0x7FFFFFFF
```